# Websocekt connection not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, websocket, internet-explorer-11

I have the follwoing java script that should is used by calling 
initConnection("User_1", 50123);

This works fine in Firefox, but as it comes to internet explorer (11) is seems not to work and I'm a bit confused where it breakes.

```
const g_PROT = "ws://";
const g_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
const g_INTERVAL = 5000;
const g_CONT = "_CONTINUE";

function initConnection(beatMessage, port) {
    var url = g_PROT + g_HOST + ":" + port;
    ws = new WebSocket(url);
    ws.onopen = function () {
        console.log("WebSocket connection starting for message: " + beatMessage);
    };
    window['beatMessage'] = beatMessage;

    // Heart Beat
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var aliveMessage = beatMessage + g_CONT;
        ws.send(aliveMessage);
    }, g_INTERVAL);

    var aliveMessage = beatMessage + g_CONT;
    ws.send(aliveMessage);
}

// Send close message
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var closeMessage = beatMessage + "_CLOSING";
    ws.send(closeMessage);
};
```

In Console I get: `SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError` with reference to the line where `var aliveMessage = beatMessage + g_CONT;` is called in the initConnection method

Comment: Please check whether it is showing any error message in console. Let us know if it showing any error or warning can help to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: added the log message form console.